# How to load tp_smapi on Thinkpad X120e

Tags: linux, ubuntu, thinkpad

My brand new Thinkpad X120e is working well with Ubuntu Natty.  Now I want to get the [tp_smapi module](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi) to work so I can control battery charge behavior.  Unfortunately I get "no Thinkpad embedded controller" (below).

The thinkwiki tp_smapi page says in this case "you should [upgrade your BIOS](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/BIOS_Upgrade).  Some early BIOS (like 1.x on the X31) don't handle the embedded controller".  But in my case, dmidecode suggests I'm already using the almost-newest [BIOS from IBM](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-74392).

```
# apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms
...(works)...
# modprobe -v tp_smapi
WARNING: Error inserting thinkpad_ec (/lib/modules/2.6.38-7-generic/updates/dkms/thinkpad_ec.ko): No such device
FATAL: Error inserting tp_smapi (/lib/modules/2.6.38-7-generic/updates/dkms/tp_smapi.ko): No such device
# tail -1 /var/log/syslog
Apr 19 23:45:05 xilotl kernel: [ 5552.149408] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
# dmidecode -s bios-version
8FET26WW (1.10 )
```

Any other idea how to make this work?

UPDATE: Here are other relevant portions of `dmidecode` (that is, `dmidecode -t0 -t1 -t11`):

```
Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: LENOVO
    Version: 8FET26WW (1.10 )
    Release Date: 03/09/2011
    ...

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 0596CTO
    Version: ThinkPad X120e
    ...

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: OEM default string
```

Answer (score 7):

I was able to make this work by editing the source code of `thinkpad_ec.c`.

The code expects that when you run `dmidecode -t 11` your output should mention "IBM ThinkPad Embedded Controller".  However, the new Thinkpad X120e has a good embedded controller which is not mentioned under `dmidecode -t 11`.  As a result, the code failed with the error "thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!".

To sidestep this check, I added ThinkPad X120e to the current list of whitelisted ThinkPad models in `thinkpad_ec.c`, then rebuilt the module.  It loaded successfully and I was able to set my battery's stop-charge-threshold in /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0 as advertised.

---

**If you are a Thinkpad X120e user and want to use tp_smapi module now**, here's how I got past the module load failure:

```
$ sudo su
# apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms
...(works)...
# modprobe -v tp_smapi
WARNING: Error inserting thinkpad_ec (/lib/modules/2.6.38-7-generic/updates/dkms/thinkpad_ec.ko): No such device
FATAL: Error inserting tp_smapi (/lib/modules/2.6.38-7-generic/updates/dkms/tp_smapi.ko): No such device
# tail -1 /var/log/syslog
Apr 19 23:45:05 xilotl kernel: [ 5552.149408] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
```

edit the crucial file using `vi /usr/src/tp-smapi-0.40/thinkpad_ec.c` to add the line marked with +:

```
diff --git a/thinkpad_ec.c b/thinkpad_ec.c
index a924d18..90d117e 100644
--- a/thinkpad_ec.c
+++ b/thinkpad_ec.c
@@ -460,6 +460,7 @@ static int __init check_dmi_for_ec(void)
                TP_DMI_MATCH("IBM", "ThinkPad A30"),
                TP_DMI_MATCH("IBM", "ThinkPad T23"),
                TP_DMI_MATCH("IBM", "ThinkPad X24"),
+               TP_DMI_MATCH("LENOVO", "ThinkPad X120e"),
                { .ident = NULL }
        };
        return dmi_find_substring(DMI_DEV_TYPE_OEM_STRING,
```

rebuild the module:

```
# dkms remove -m tp-smapi -v 0.40 --all
# dkms add -m tp-smapi -v 0.40
# dkms build -m tp-smapi -v 0.40
# dkms install -m tp-smapi -v 0.40
# modprobe tp-smapi
```

and finally try using it:

```
# cd /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0
# echo 60 > stop_charge_thresh
```

As hwong557 mentions, add `tp_smapi` to `/etc/modules` so it will load automatically on boot.

---

**If you are the `tp_smapi` module maintainer** or other knowledgeable person who can get this fixed "right":  Is this the "right" fix?  Should Thinkpad X120e be permanently added to this whitelist, or is there another way that it should check for existence of the embedded controller?  I hope either this change or some other fix for the problem will be added to the upstream source.

Comment: You should submit your patch to maintainer so this can be evaluated for inclusion. Good work.

Answer (score 2):

A fix on **Arch Linux**

Download the [tp_smapi](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=45862) modules from AUR.

Build and install: `makepkg -i`

Attempt to load the module:

```
$ sudo  modprobe -v tp_smapi   
insmod /lib/modules/2.6.38-ARCH/extra/thinkpad_ec.ko.gz 
WARNING: Error inserting thinkpad_ec (/lib/modules/2.6.38-ARCH/extra/thinkpad_ec.ko.gz): No such device
FATAL: Error inserting tp_smapi (/lib/modules/2.6.38-ARCH/extra/tp_smapi.ko.gz): No such device
```

Check the sys log:

```
$ dmesg | tail -1           
[ 1009.371778] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
```

Edit `src/tp_smapi-0.40/thinkpad_ec.c` as krubo's answer says, adding a patch to the package:

```
--- thinkpad_ec.c.orig  2011-05-15 13:35:28.556634244 -0700
+++ thinkpad_ec.c       2011-05-15 13:35:40.466634616 -0700
@@ -460,6 +460,7 @@
                TP_DMI_MATCH("IBM", "ThinkPad A30"),
                TP_DMI_MATCH("IBM", "ThinkPad T23"),
                TP_DMI_MATCH("IBM", "ThinkPad X24"),
+               TP_DMI_MATCH("LENOVO", "ThinkPad X120e"),
                { .ident = NULL }
        };
        return dmi_find_substring(DMI_DEV_TYPE_OEM_STRING,
```

Edit the PKGBUILD to include the new patch:

```
patch -Np1 < "$srcdir/thinkpad-x120e.patch"
```

Remove any previously built package, and rebuild and install the package (`makepkg -i`) with this patch

Load the module, and you should be in business:

```
$ sudo modprobe  tp_smapi
$ dmesg | tail -1
[ 1735.966431] tp_smapi successfully loaded (smapi_port=0xb0).
$ ls /sys/devices/platform/smapi 
ac_connected  BAT0  BAT1  driver  modalias  power 
smapi_request  subsystem  uevent
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried [krubo's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11670/how-to-load-tp-smapi-on-thinkpad-x120e/12496#12496) for my Thinkpad T420. However at the last step with `install`, I had to add a `--force` to make the modprobe successful; otherwise it gave me the same error as initially.

However when I try to modify my battery settings, the `echo` command to `/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/stop_charge_thresh` is successful, but upon reading it, `cat` still gives 100.

Also upon reboot, the module is no longer loaded, and I need to manually modprobe again. This was fixed by adding `tp_smapi` to `/etc/modules`.

However, I'm happy to report that hdaps is working; I had to change the last setting in `/etc/defaults/hdaps`, `FORCEENABLE` to `yes`. I checked it using this link: [Verifying hdapsd is working (Thinkpad Wiki)](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_protect_the_harddisk_through_APS#Verifying_hdapsd_is_working).

Comment: Could you post the output of `dmidecode -t0 -t1 -t11` so we know what exact system you tested?  Also, +1 for adding `tp_smapi` to `/etc/modules`

Comment: I do have a fix for stop_charge_thresh (Debian-style), but have not managed to get start_charge_thresh working yet: https://github.com/ginkel/tp_smapi/commit/8c606b476b5859b2d6798e6df15aa0316ca6a206